# Apache Virtual Host not accessible from local network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2

I have setup a Virtual Host with Apache2 with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

It is possible to access the website from the outside.

```
example.com
```

But if I enter `example.com` from another system in my local network, it opens my router configuration page.

I forwarded my routers port 80 to my servers port 8080 in my network.

But I would like to access the website as well from my other systems in the local network. Is this possible?

Comment: This is a name resolution (DNS) issue.  You need your internal systems to resolve to your internal IP of the server, and leave the external DNS alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to access the web server from inside using the outside address, your router must translate your source address too. This is called NAT reflection.

If it doesn't, the webserver sends the return traffic directly to your computer and the TCP connection can't be established because your computer talks to the outside address of the webserver and gets the traffic back from the inside address.

If the router translates your source address the webserver sends the return traffic to the router from where it gets relayed to your computer.

Using different DNS addresses inside and outside (Split DNS) as Brandon Xavier suggested in the comment would be another solution. This would not require NAT reflection.

Comment: Good point!  This certainly can be addressed as a NAT reflection/SNAT/asymmetric routing issue - I usually go the name resolution route to avoid having to wake my network engineers up ;-)